# std::map::find doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I'm trying to keep information in `std::map`. But I have a problem with `find`:

```
typedef map<string, string, equal_to<string>> MAP_STRING2STRING;
....
MAP_STRING2STRING map;
MAP_STRING2STRING::const_iterator iter;
```

When I try to find `key`, I get the following error:

```
iter = map.find(key);
```

[image: Error from Visual C++]

What am I doing wrong?

This error appears only when I have something in `map`.

Comment: `equal_to` is not the right kind of comparison. You need strict weak ordering (less-than or greater-than type comparison).

Comment: When the key is `std::string`, you usually don't need to pass a third template argument to `std::map` at all; the default will be `std::less<std::string>`, which is fine unless you need some special ordering.

Comment: DONT_USE_ALL_UPPERCASE - except for MACROS. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Your map has the wrong kind of comparison functor. You need [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) (less-than or greater-than type comparison), not equality. You can just omit the comparison functor parameter and use a less-than comparison for `std::string`. This implements strict weak ordering via a lexicographical comparison of strings:

```
typedef map<string, string> MAP_STRING2STRING;
```

This is equivalent to

```
typedef map<string, string, less<string> > MAP_STRING2STRING;
```

Internally, the map uses the strict weak ordering comparison to both order itself, and determine whether two keys are the equal.

The third template parameter allows you to instantiate a map with a custom ordering criterion. For example, this would create a map with the reverse ordering of the one above:

```
typedef map<string, string, greater<string> > MAP_STRING2STRING;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple map from `std::string` to `std::string`, just use `map<string, string>` (drop that `equal_to<string>` bogus "comparator").

Moreover, since you have a variable named "`map`", this can cause conflict with the STL `map` class. Either change the variable name (e.g. call it `myMap`), or use the `std::` namespace prefix for `std::map` class:

```
typedef map<string, string> MAP_STRING2STRING;
....
MAP_STRING2STRING myMap;
```

---

In addition, since from the error message you are using VS2010, you can use the convenient `auto` C++11 keyword, to avoid the "clutter" of `MAP_STRING2STRING::const_iterator`, and just use:

```
auto iter = myMap.find(someKey);
```

Comment: WRT your last comment, you _can_ use auto, but you may want to use the actual type name to make the code clearer.  (It depends a bit on the scope of `iter`.  In a small function, where all of the actions on the variable are immediately clear, I'll use `auto`.  I would never use it for a variable at namespace scope, however.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree with you on not using `auto` for variables at namesapce scope.